# Subcaption package messing with caption format and not fully aligned figures

Tags: subcaption, ieeeaccess

I am using [IEEE Access template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-access-template) to write a document and I've added the `subcaption` package in the `figure*` environment in order to create a full page subfigures. In this I have two problems, the first is that it messed up my captions, which are now centralized for other figures and the `Figure N` is now uppercased. The second one is that my images don't have the same height and thus the (a), (b), (c) are not properly aligned.

[image]

**EDIT**: With the MWE given by @Zarko I understood what I was suppose to give you to properly ask the question, below you have the result of the MWE and the MWE itself. As you can see, the `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` are not aligned, the `FIGURE` caption is all in capital letters and the caption itself is centralized.

I would like to know how to:

- move the `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` to be in the same Y position (supposing X for width and Y for height).
- have the `FIGURE` to be displayed as `Figure`
- flush it left instead of having it centralized

A more graphical way of explaining it is shown in the last picture (which is a bad paint drawing I made with the mousepad from my laptop so I excuse myself for the poor quality).

I thank everyone who commented and I hope I made my question clearer

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\let\setyear\year
\let\year\TeXyear

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 0.3\textheight]{example-image-duck}%{figs/AFig.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:AFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{figs/BFIG.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:BFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{figs/Cfig.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:CFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Three figures: (a) AFig, (b) BFig, (c) CFig}
\end{figure*}

\EOD{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Please merge your code fragment into one, complete small document, which we can test as it is. Since we haven't your images, please use instead them use `example-image` which is provided by the `graphicx` package.

Comment: You probably have the problem with use of `tikz` package. See answer to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528975/how-to-use-tikz .

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the mess, I have edited the post in order to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composing an MWE from your code fragments and considering [@Phelype Oleinik answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528975/how-to-use-tikz-and-ieeeaccess) for work around of bug in the `IEEEacces`, gives the following result:

[image]

Note: Position of caption is determined by `IEEEaccess` document class as is required by journal style. I would not change this. However, if you anyway like do this, than include in document preamble `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}`. In this case you will obtain:

[image]

```
\let\TeXyear\year
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\let\setyear\year
\let\year\TeXyear

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} %% used in the second example)
% 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{figs/AFig.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:AFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{figs/BFIG.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:BFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.33\linewidth}%33% of the line
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{figs/Cfig.PNG}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:CFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Three figures: (a) AFig, (b) BFig, (c) CFig}
\end{figure*}

\EOD{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the MWE. I have modified the post to see if I make myself clearer and I excuse myself for the mess.