# Error loading TikZ in IEEEaccess class

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, ieeeaccess

I tried to use IEEEaccess class (found from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beatrizgoa/latex/master/ieeeaccess.cls) together with Ti*k*Z version 3.1.5b

```
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

test

\EOD{}

\end{document}
```

but I get this error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctio
ns.random.code.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.33 \ifnum
           \c@pgfmath@counta=0
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra \fi.
l.35 \fi

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470103/4427

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a bug in `IEEEaccess`. It redefines TeX's `\year` primitive to set the year of the publication (so that you can type `\year{2020}`). That breaks Ti*k*Z (and *several* other packages) that rely on `\year` having its primitive meaning.

You can work around that issue by tepmorarily saving `\year` as `\TeXyear` before loading `IEEEaccess`, and then restoring it after the class is loaded. To be able to set the year in your publication you can also save `IEEEaccess`'s `\year` as, say, `\setyear`:

```latex
\let\TeXyear\year
\documentclass{IEEEaccess}
\let\setyear\year
\let\year\TeXyear

\usepackage{tikz}

% \year{2020}
\setyear{2020}

\begin{document}

test

\EOD{}

\end{document}
```