# Cannot Include ORCID in IEEE ACCESS template

Tags: ieeeaccess

I am trying to include ORCID in IEEE ACCESS Template by following this [IEEEtran - How to include ORCID in TeX/PDF with PdfLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445563/ieeetran-how-to-include-orcid-in-tex-pdf-with-pdflatex)

I don't understand why if I create an empty project on overleaf and put the code in the above link, then it works fine, but when I put the code into IEEE ACCESS Template, it shows a bunch of error like this:

```
    Missing number, \usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex, line 33
, treated as zero.

    <to be read again> 
                       \gdef 
    l.33 \ifnum
               \c@pgfmath@counta=0
    A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
    (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
    look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

    ! Extra \fi.
    l.35 \fi
```

The problem is at line 33, there is no problem at all. Please help, thank you

Comment: This is due to a bug in `ieeeaccess`, making it incompatible with the `tikz` package. You can see the discussions at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528975/226 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91262/226

Comment: Thank you. I handled it. Cheers fam.

Comment: Key Jun, can you post your solution?

Comment: (That system-generated message makes no sense.) I'm voting to close this question b/c the given links explain what happens and give solution.