# How to use the ''easyReview'' package in IEEEACCESS class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ieeeaccess

I want to use the **easyReview** package in IEEEACCESS LaTeX class, but it shows an error with the additional used package as given below. I need help to use **easyReview** package. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
% \usepackage{easyReview} % for \comment, \alert, etc.

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


% \usepackage{arydshln}
% \setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
% \setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
% \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=cyan,
}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,nicefrac,float}
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{setspace}   % <--- new
\usepackage[font={sf,small,stretch=0.84},
            labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}
            ]{caption}  % <--- new

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
```

I have solved the issue with the hints given by @imnothere and related question  tex.stackexchange.com/q/470103/4427

```
% save the meaning of \year
\let\texyear\year

\documentclass{ieeeaccess}

% temporary fix for loading expl3 and PGF
\let\ieeeaccessyear\year
\let\year\texyear

%\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{easyReview} % for \comment, \alert, etc.
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
% undo the fix and define a color compatible with xcolor
\let\year\ieeeaccessyear
\definecolor{accessblue}{RGB}{0,105,154}
\begin{document}

test

\EOD{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If there is any solution available, please help me.

Comment: `easyReview` uses tikz. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528982

Comment: Thank you @imnothere